# QtGraphicsView size in QTGraphicsScene

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, coding-style, qt4

I'm having trouble getting my QtGraphicsView to take up 100% of the window I'm working in. Is there a way to set the view size to take up 100% of the graphics window that is created?

```
QApplication app(argc, argv);

QGraphicsScene * scene = new QGraphicsScene();

int counter = 1000;


scene->setSceneRect(0, 0, counter, counter);//scene size

QGraphicsEllipseItem * item = new QGraphicsEllipseItem(0, scene);

item->setRect(0,0, 1000.0, 1000.0);

QGraphicsView view(scene);

view.setRect(100, 100);
view.setRenderHints(QPainter::Antialiasing);
view.show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QGraphicsView` should have a method(slot) called `showFullScreen` since it inherits `QWidget`
, which should do what you want.

Comment: Thanks! Anyway I could now get the size of the screen from this? So I can use it in the rest of my code? Thanks

Comment: @JonMorehouse: If you want screen information, you should use the [QDesktopWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdesktopwidget.html) API instead.

Comment: Thats right! You can retrieve the desktop geometry by: `QApplication::desktop()->screenGeometry();` which returns a `QRect`

Comment: Hello, could you guys explain what the difference between the two is? I'm creating a game with lots of moving objects on the screen and was under the impression that this would be best, but obviously the QApplication desktop provides screen information which i need?

Comment: I think we're talking about different things. In your question, you asked for a solution to make your graphicsview fullscreen. But in your first comment to the answer, you ask for a hint to get the screen-dimensions, which was answered in the following comments. I just wrote it down what jmk suggested. So: To switch to fullscreen, use `showFullscreen`, and to retrieve the screen-dimensions, either use the `QDesktopWidget` approach and get it's geometry or get the geometry of your view, which should be the same result, if you used `showFullScreen` before

Comment: Okay, thanks. Sorry for the confusion, I'm still new to QT and am still figuring some things out.

Comment: I was able to call View::contentsRect() which returned a QTRect with the coordinates on the view so all worked great